# Issue in showing the Decimal part of the Number

Tags: java, android, double, decimal, number-formatting

I am working on to create a calculator but have some issue in showing the decimal part after the number. I have **keys on calculator are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,00 and one backspace key**.

[image: I have to enter value like this]

On Pressing 1 it will show 0.01

Then onPressing 2 o/p 0.12

Then onPressing 3 o/p 1.23

Like that we will add show the numbers on the screen. Below is the code i am using to do this task

```
      @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.number1:
                    calcValue(.01);
                break;
                case R.id.number2:
                    calcValue(.02);
                    break;
                case R.id.number3:
                    calcValue(.03);
                    break;
                case R.id.number4:
                    calcValue(.04);
                    break;
                case R.id.number5:
                    calcValue(.05);
                    break;
                case R.id.number6:
                    calcValue(.06);
                    break;
                case R.id.number7:
                    calcValue(.07);
                    break;
                case R.id.number8:
                    calcValue(.08);
                    break;
                case R.id.number9:
                    calcValue(.09);
                    break;
                case R.id.number0:
                    enteredAmt = enteredAmt * 10.0 +(.0 * 100)/ 100.0;
                    roundEnteredPrice();
                    roundMyData(enteredAmt,2);

                    System.out.println("enteredAmt before:"+enteredAmt);
                    enteredAmt = (enteredAmt*100.0)/100.0;
                    System.out.println("enteredAmt after:"+enteredAmt);
                    valueEnteredTextview.setText(""+enteredAmt);
                    break;
                case R.id.number00:
                    enteredAmt = enteredAmt * 100.0 + Math.floor(.0 * 100)/ 100.0;
                    roundEnteredPrice();
                    roundMyData(enteredAmt,2);
                    System.out.println("enteredAmt before:"+enteredAmt);
                    enteredAmt = (enteredAmt*100.0)/100.0;
                    System.out.println("enteredAmt after:"+enteredAmt);
                    valueEnteredTextview.setText(""+enteredAmt);
                    break;
                case R.id.backspaceButton:
                    enteredAmt = 0.00;
                    valueEnteredTextview.setText("$" +0.00);
                    break;
    }
    private void calcValue(double d) {
                enteredAmt = enteredAmt + Math.floor(d * 100)/ 100.0;
                System.out.println("enteredAmt befor:"+enteredAmt);
                enteredAmt = (Math.floor(enteredAmt*100.0)/100.0);
                System.out.println("enteredAmt after:"+enteredAmt);
                valueEnteredTextview.setText(""+enteredAmt);
            }

private void roundEnteredPrice() {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(enteredAmt);
        BigDecimal res = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
        System.out.println("Big Decimal" + res.toPlainString());
        double entered = Double.parseDouble(res.toPlainString());
        System.out.println("Entered Amount: "+entered);
    }

    private void roundMyData(double enteredAmt2, int numberOfDigitsAfterDecimal) {
        double p = (float)Math.pow(10,numberOfDigitsAfterDecimal);
        enteredAmt2 = enteredAmt2 * p;
        double tmp = Math.floor(enteredAmt2)/p;
        System.out.println("~~~~~~tmp~~~~~"+tmp);
```

Now my issue is **it didn't show the last entered Zero**
Like if i have entered 1,2,0 the **expected value to show is 1.20** but **it shows 1.2**
If i press next digit then it shows the zero like i press 4 then output is 12.04

I have tried with Big Decimal also it gives us the zero but proved some wired result sometimes like if i enter 1,0,2,0 expected value is 10.20 but it gives value as 10.19. 
Suggest me something to do that and where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `String.Format`

```
String value = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.2f", yourValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to format it as per your need:

```
double d = 1.234567;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.print(df.format(d));
```

Comment: I have tried with DecimalFormat but it didn't print Zero comes at the end. Like it print 1.20 as 1.2

Answer (score 1):

Use a formatter to format decimal values

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
```